# create a promise which encompass a recursive function

Tags: typescript, recursion, promise, es6-promise

I'm writing a simple recursive function that is calling a function `driver` that returns a promise. And my `aaa` function has to return a Promise at the end of the calls.

So this code is the simplification of my issue:

## Code:

```
function aaa(index) {
      driver(index)
      .then(index => {
            if (index < 100)
                  aaa(index);
            else
                  console.log('finito' + index);     
      })

}

function driver(index) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
            resolve(index + 1);
      });
}

aaa(0);
```

## My Solution:

```
function aaa(index) {
      console.log(index);
      return Promise.resolve(index)
            .then((index) => {
                  driver(index)
                        .then( index => {
                              if (index < 100)
                                    return aaa(index);
                              else
                                    return Promise.resolve(index);
                        });
            });
}

function driver(index) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
            resolve(index + 1);
      });
}

function doTheThing() {
  Promise.resolve(0).then(aaa)
  .then(()=>{
    alert('end');
  });
}

doTheThing();
```

But I still have an editor warning in the last `then` of the `aaa` function which is:

```
Argument of type '(index: {}) => Promise<void> | Promise<{}>'
is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: {}) => void | PromiseLike<void>'.
  Type 'Promise<void> | Promise<{}>' is not assignable to type 'void | PromiseLike<void>'.
    Type 'Promise<{}>' is not assignable to type 'void | PromiseLike<void>'.
```

Comment: ohhhh No!!!! Who is disliking my Question !!! explain why !!!!!

Comment: first of all what exactly is your question?
and on very first look 'aaa' is void function so u cant call aaa(0).then...

Comment: I want to transform it to Async Function that is returning a promise

Comment: I have to wait until the end of this function to execute some code !!! I'm blocked Men !!

Comment: i am not sure what are u expecting from this but... pass resolve function as recursive, dont call drive again...

Comment: No need to wrap your function in `Promise.resolve().then(…)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my `aaa` function has to return a Promise at the end of the calls

... That is exactly what isn't happening in your first code. But also the version with `doTheThing` runs into an error because there is no `return` in the line with `driver(index)`.

For it to return a promise, you can stick with the first version of your code, but add `return` in two places:

```js
function aaa(index) {
    return driver(index).then(index => {
//  ^^^^^^ (1)
        if (index < 100) {
            return aaa(index);
//          ^^^^^^ (2)
        } else {
            console.log('finito' + index);     
        }
    })
}

function driver(index) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        resolve(index + 1);
    });
}

function doTheThing() {
    Promise.resolve(0).then(aaa).then(() => {
        console.log('end');
    });
}

doTheThing();
```

Note that in `doTheThing` it is not *really* necessary to do `Promise.resolve(0).then(aaa).then`. You can just do `aaa(0).then`.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really have to do anything special –

```js
const aaa = async n =>
  n < 100
    ? driver (n) .then (aaa)
    : n

const driver = async n =>
  n + 1

aaa (0) .then
  ( res => console .log ("res", res)
  , err => console .error ("err", err)
  )
  // res 100
```

Above, `async` functions are guaranteed to return a Promise. But if you don't believe me that it still works, here's some added proof :D

```js
const aaa = async n =>
{ if (n >= 100)
    return n
  else if (n % 10 === 0)
    return status (n) .then (driver) .then (aaa)
  else
    return driver (n) .then (aaa)
}

const driver = async n =>
  new Promise (r => setTimeout (r, 15, n + 1)) // simulate 15ms delay

const status = async n =>
{ console .log ("progress: %d%", n)
  return n
}

aaa (0) .then
  ( res => console .log ("res", res)
  , err => console .error ("err", err)
  )
```

Output

```
progress: 0%
progress: 10%
progress: 20%
progress: 30%
progress: 40%
progress: 50%
progress: 60%
progress: 70%
progress: 80%
progress: 90%
res 100
```

Comment: Thank You Bro, You are a real JavaScript Ghoul.